# how do I place the question number above a tikz image

Tags: tikz-pgf, exam

My code is below. I can't figure how to place the question number above the tikz image. Thanks for the help.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[label={[fill=white]:$23$ }] () at (0,0) {};
        \node[label={[fill=white]:$65$ }] () at (0,-.5) {};
        \node[label={[fill=white]:$+$ }] () at (-.5,-.5) {}; 
        \draw (-.5,-.5)--(.3,-.5);
        \node[label={[fill=white]:$\longrightarrow$ }] () at (.75,0) {};
        \node[label={[fill=white]:$\longrightarrow$ }] () at (.75,-.5) {};

    \node[label={[fill=white]:$+$ }] () at (1.5,-.5) {}; 
    \draw (1.5,-.5)--(2.3,-.5);   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide compilable code rater than code fragments. `\question` is not defined by default. (Nor, for that matter, is `tikzpicture`.) However, the answer is probably to use the `baseline` option to the `tikzpicture`. If that's not the right name, it's similar - just look in the manual. I'd test if I had code.

Comment: Why do you label empty nodes instead of just using nodes and why the white fill? Why not just `\node (A) at (0,0) {$23$};`? With this you can use the above mentioned `baseline` option to tell you picture to align the base of the first node with the base of node `(A)`.

Comment: But why using Ti*k*Z in the first place and not just a plan `tabular` (with `\cline`)?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of making your code snippet minimally compilable by adding four lines at the top and two lines at the bottom. Feel free to revert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of the `base` anchor of the first node and set the `baseline` option to this anchor. You should probably just place the contents inside the nodes and not in the labels, because this will shift everything and makes your code overly complicated. You might also want to position the nodes relative to each other (or maybe even use a `matrix`).

An example how to use the `base` anchor with `baseline` would be:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(A.base)]
        \node (A) at (0,0) {23};
        \node (B) at (0,-.5) {65};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But for this task, I don't recommend using Ti*k*Z. Instead, I would actually just use a `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question 
    \begin{tabular}[t]{ c w{r}{0.5cm} c c w{r}{0.5cm} }
            & 23 & $\longrightarrow$ &     & \\
        $+$ & 65 & $\longrightarrow$ & $+$ & \\
        \cline{1-2} \cline{4-5}
    \end{tabular}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Since the contents of the little table are all math-y, one might also employ an `array` environment instead of a `tabular` envirionment.

Comment: Both of these are perfect. I can use tabular for this but the baseline is also gonna help with other project later. Thanks a lot